# How to overwrite with Json.dump?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to write to a JSON file after pulling some information from a database but anytime I use `json.dump` it reads and writes to file correctly but for every subsequent execution, the code crashes as I've noticed `json.dump` fails to overwrite my json file upon second execution after successfully extracting data, but instead appends broken bits of the extracted data to the end of the file.

EDIT: The overwriting works successfully when this condition (`if monitor_Data['monitor_name'] == k['name'] and k['id'] == m['id'] \ and k['modified'] < modification_date(file_Path):`) is taken out. However, once I put it back in content is appended upon multiple execution.

```
            for k in listOfMonitors:
                for m in monitor_Name_And_Mod_Date_List:
                    if k['id'] == m['id'] and monitor_Data['monitor_name'] == m['name']:

                        print("test")
                        print("Value: ", k['id'])
                        if k['id'] not in monitor_Data: # NEED TO FIX UPDATE CONDITION
                            print("attempting update")
                            monitor_Data.update(k)
                            # print("updated")
                            # print(json.dumps(monitor_Data))
                            jsonfile.seek(0)
                            print("pending....")
                            json.dump(monitor_Data, jsonfile)
                            print("updated")

                            if monitor_Data['monitor_name'] == k['name'] and k['id'] == m['id'] \
                                    and k['modified'] < modification_date(file_Path):
                                print("test 2")
                                deleted = False
                                # Delete a monitor
                                if deleted is False:
                                    api.Monitor.delete(k['id'])
                                    # Force delete a monitor to override warnings
                                    # api.Monitor.delete(k['id'], force=True)
                                    deleted = True
                                print("DEBUG: ", deleted)

                                if deleted is True:
                                    try:
                                        # Create a new monitor
                                        print("test 3")
                                        createMonitor(monitor_Data)
                                    finally:
                                        jsonfile.close()
            else:
                continue
except IOError as e:
    logging.error("Failed to open monitor_config.json " + str(e))
```

This circled information is what happens when I run my program multiple times, sometime the data that gets appended is longer.

[image: Example of what happens]

Comment: Can you throw out all the code from your sample that has nothing to do with trying to write a JSON file?

Comment: @Tomalak sure, I've done so.. the parts I left in have a link to the issue